vb.net interacting with a word mail merge
I have a vba script that manipulates a word document that has been set-up with a mail merge tohave the resulting merged document in a format that our business would prefer, but isn't a default output available by word.I've been asked to try and develop thecode so that it can be incorporated in to a vb.net program used by the majority of the company as at the moment for front end staff to use it they either have to a) send my department the word document so we can embed the vba macro code or b) we'll have to put together some documentation show them how to add the vba code themselves, neither of these options are perfect so I've been looking at the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library to function this.
the bit I'm stuck on is one of the bits required is that there be a combo drop down box which is populated with the merge fields available to the documents.
based on my research so far I have the following code:
Dim wrdDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
Dim wordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(txtMergeDocPath.Text, , True)
Dim fields As Word.MailMergeFields = wordDoc.MailMerge.Fields
For Each field As Word.MailMergeField In .Fields
    cmbFields.Items.Add(field.name)
Next

the current error is 'name' is not a member of 'MailMergeField' does anyone know the correct property so that the mail merge field name is added in to the combobox?

So why isn't your mailmerge main document already formatted as your company requires before running the mailmerge? On top of that, the code you posted suggests what you're working with isn't even a mailmerge main document. If it were, all the user would need to after opening the document is to Finish the merge.

@macropodas a company we do  work for a lot of different clients and so when it comes to issuing letters and things each client will have a different letter styles ( branding etc. so there isn't one 'template' that can be used for everyone and whilst the teams actually producing the letter will make and put together a letter each time as required but there's still a bit of vba code that we'd like to have run on the 'finished' product so as I've stated that still requires either the administration team or a member of my team to go and put the vba code in to the letter via the developer tab.

Well, the sensible way of dealing with that would be to have a different mailmerge main document for each client. No code required.

@macropod I work in the IT department of a corporate business, they don't budget for 'sensible' when my office was a separate company we had a third party contractor that put together a custom letter template with macro code already attached to a ribbon button ( for a different problem) I suggested going down that route again but that was turned down for 'reasons that I couldn't bebothered to argue against, my office is now owned by a larger parent company that buys up other small- medium business' that are in the same industry.

@jonssonI will once I've hada chance to try them out I can up vote them for usefulness but I can't fully accept or reject them until I've actually tried them.

You can search for Microsoft's documentation. Nothing about a Name.
However, there is a property, Code, which will contain information about the merge field. The format will be like

{MERGEFIELD ItemName.PropertyName additionalOptionalInfo}

So if the ItemName.PropertyName is what you seek, you can split that string and retrieve it,
For Each field As Word.MailMergeField In fields
    Dim s = field.Code.Split(" "c)(1).Split("."c)
    Dim name = s(0)
    Dim prop = s(1)
    cmbFields.Items.Add(name)
    ' or
    cmbFields.Items.Add(prop)
Next

Depending on the contents of those strings, one should be what you're looking for.

wordDoc.MailMerge.Fields is the collection of placeholders in the Mail Merge Main Document.
You can get the collection of field names that should be available to the merge from either wordDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames (which just contains the names) or wordDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields (which contains the values too).
[I am not sure whether there is ever a difference between the names in these two collections in modern versions of Word - perhaps at one time one collection was supposed to have the names as used in your MERGEFIELD field codes and the other one was supposed to have the names that were actually in the data source. But that's not how it is now - e.g. if you have the name "x y" in the data source, you have to use "x_y" in Word, and both FieldNames and DataFields use "x_y".)
